# Is there way to get notified when a connection is made from a consumer to Azure Relay Connection?

Tags: azure-relay

Here is my use case:

- Configure Azure Relay with one connection
- Consumer connects to relay with this connection
- We push information to the consumer via Azure Relay
- Consumer connection drops and we detect the error on our side
- We stop pushing the events
- Some time later consumer connects again

At this point, I would like to start pushing the events. Is there way I can be notified by azure that new connection is made to my Azure Relay resource and I can start pushing events to that connection?